# What is Databinding? How it can be used in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

What is DataBinding? How it can be used in Asp.Net MVC?

Can anyone give a real time example for DataBinding?

Comment: asp.net mvc supports data binding. You can bind data to some model and post it back when the form is submitted. Please read a good asp.net mvc tutorial or watch some videos.

Answer (score 2):

MVC doesn't use data bindings like old web api.

You have to use model bindings in a MVC or MVVM approach.

Take a look here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you explain what is DataBindng?

Comment: This answer is wrong. asp.net mvc supports data binding. You can bind data to some model and post it back when the form is submitted. Please read a good asp.net mvc tutorial or watch some videos.

Comment: The answer is right. You're confusing data binding ("old way" to bind a control with it's data) with model binding (the mechanism that asp.net mvc use to bind data passed from a webpage to an action through an http call).  reference: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/model-binding-in-asp.net-mvc